# No bean named 'shiroFilter' is defined

Tags: java, spring, shiro

I am current embeding Shiro into my **Spring Web** application.

In `web.xml`, I added:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

In `servlet-context.xml`, I added:

```
    <beans:bean id="shiroFilter" name="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
        <beans:property name="filterChainDefinitions">
            <beans:value>
                # some example chain definitions:
                /admin/** = authc, roles[admin]
                /docs/** = authc, perms[document:read]
                /** = authc
                # more URL-to-FilterChain definitions here
            </beans:value>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
        <beans:property name="realm" ref="myRealm"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="myRealm" class="com.hersbitcloud.cancercloud.ShiroRealm">

    </beans:bean>
```

And because I haven't found a solution for the JDBD realm, so I am just using the `AuthenticatingRealm` as:

```
public class ShiroRealm extends AuthenticatingRealm {

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken arg0) throws AuthenticationException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, I got the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'shiroFilter' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:698)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4640)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Where is your `servlet-context.xml` declared?

Comment: @Pillar It's in `\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\spring\appServlet\servlet-context.xml`. It's created by default and many other beans can be used correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I mean where do you use it? Show its `<listener>`, for example.

Comment: @Pillar I am following this [link](http://shiro.apache.org/spring.html), the first step in Web Application.

Comment: It says _In addition to your other Spring web.xml elements (ContextLoaderListener, Log4jConfigListener, etc)_. Let's see those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your servlet-context.xml in context-param, something like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,
    /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

do not put it in servlet contextConfigLocation